# What does "jolly well" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

A friend of mine sent me this sentence: "This is London: Whatever you do to us, we will drink tea, and jolly well carry on".
Everything is clear except for the expression "jolly well". I have asked to a teacher and he says it is old-fashioned and equivalent to "very well". Can you explain better when it could be used and, if it's possible, the origins of this expression? I've never heard it before.

Comment: You can use [Jolly well](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jolly-well) for emphasis.

Comment: You will find numerous explanations and examples of its use if you google it.

Answer (score 1):

*Jolly*, from Old French *jolif* = “merry, pretty” has been used informally as an emphatic adverb meaning “very,greatly” since the 16th century.

*Jolly well* is likely to have originated as a 'minced' form of the adverbial oath *damn well*, meaning approximately “thoroughly” or “emphatically”.